# Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' with springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I am building springboot application but while launching the application it throws following exception.
I am configuring ServletContext through ServletContextInitializer bean. 
Any help or input will be appreciated.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [..!/BOOT-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.6.1.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.findWebApplicationContext(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:297)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.ServletContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 26 more
```

below is gradle dependency. I hope it will help.

```
compile(
                "javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final",
                "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.0.Final",
                "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.2",

                'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.51',
                'ibmjceprovider:ibmjceprovider:ibmjceprovider',
                'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
        )
        compile('com.googlecode.lambdaj:lambdaj:2.3.3') {
            exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-all'
        } 
       compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.4.0')
        compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.4.0')
        compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0'
        runtime(
                'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.0.2'
        )
       configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-orm'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.messaging', module: 'spring-messaging'
        all*.resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:1.1.0'
        }
       compile(           
                'com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:1.4.10',
                'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        )
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

Comment: Add your pom.xml or build.gradle or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating ServletContextInitializer bean and within onStartup method I was creating AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.

So there I was missing to set ServletContext for this WebApplicationContext and that was creating whole havoc for me.

So finally setting setServletContext(servletContext) for this AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext object I get rid of mine issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by redundant `/out` and `/build` folders in a Gradle project in Intellij Idea.

IntelliJ Idea provides two ways to build and run Gradle projects. Either by IntelliJ internal compile and run - or by delegating builds and execution to Gradle.

Each of them creates it's own output folders for compiled classes.

IntelliJ - `/out`
Gradle - `/build`

When you switch the way to build an run (from Gradle to IntelliJ or vice versa) the output folders of the other still remain - causing duplicate classes to be on the classpath.

Unfortunately both folders are on the classpath of IntelliJ:
[sample folder structure in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFmGt.png)

For me running a Gradle `clean` or delete all `/out` folders did the trick.

Here is a Gradle task to remove `/out` folders in the whole project tree (if it's a multi project):

```
task deleteOutFolders {
    doLast {
        fileTree(dir: ".").visit {
            FileVisitDetails details ->
                if (details.directory && details.file.name == "out") {
                    println "deleting ${details}"
                    details.file.deleteDir()
                }
        }
    }
}
```